# bash script to send email with compressed files

Tags: bash

i have a debian system that runs some services. i do need to run the script and send some files to an email with a subject. the files are:
/opt/path.conf, /opt/sounds/recording.mp3, /opt/library/files/libr.conf
i would like to copy and tar.gz these three files and email them. the important thing is to leave the original files as they are. Otherwise the system will malfunction.
from the server i can email with the following:

```
mail -s "Subject" mail@example.com
```

i would like your help please, since i am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
tar /tmp/files.tar.gz /opt/path.conf /opt/sounds/recording.mp3 /opt/library/files/libr.conf
mail -s "Subject" -a /tmp/files.tar.gz mail@example.com
```